# SQLite Time range filter?

Tags: sqlite, date, time, filter

I have 2 TEXT columns 'initial_time' and 'final_time' that contains values like '01:00', '16:30', etc...

How can I filter records with a WHERE clause to achieve something like "WHERE initial_time >= my_init_value AND final_time <= my_final_value"?

my_init_value and my_final_value are string values too with the same "mask" 'hh:mm'

Comment: Why do you have these values in text columns in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try: `strftime("%H:%M", time_string)`.

So with your code: `WHERE strftime( "%H:%M", initial_time ) >= strftime( "%H:%M", my_init_value ) AND strftime( "%H:%M", final_time ) <= strftime( "%H:%M", my_final_value )`

Look [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) for more information